# I am unable understand and solve the tkinter.Tclerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am unable to understand and unable to solve a tkinter.TclError in this following code that i have written till now. Pls solve this question i have got homework to make a mp3 player program using python and i want Submitted it quickly. And also conivence i have given the tracback also.
**Code**

```
From tkinter import
root = Tk()

root.title("Creeper Awww Man MP3 Player")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Create Playlist Box 
playlist_box = Listbox(
    root,
    bg = "black",
    fg = "#4666FF",
    width = 60
)
playlist_box.pack(pady=20)

# Define Button Image For Controls
back_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/back.png')
forward_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/forward.png')
play_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/play.png')
pause_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/pause.png')
stop_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/stop.png')


# Create Button Frame
control_frame = Frame(root)
control_frame.pack(pady=20)

# Create Play/Stop etc Buttons
back_button = Button(control_frame, image=back_btn_img,)
forward_button = Button(control_frame, image=forward_btn_img,)
play_button = Button(control_frame, image=play_btn_img,)
pause_button = Button(control_frame, image=pause_btn_img,)
stop_button = Button(control_frame, image=stop_btn_img,)

back_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
forward_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
play_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
pause_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10)





root.mainloop()
```

**And Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp3_player.py", line 19, in <module>
    forward_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/forward.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "images/forward.png"
```

If you could help me I would be Thankful of you all and I would appreciate it.

Regards,

Shiven

Comment: Ive added an answer

Comment: >The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files< https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and I appreciate it

Comment: @ShivenSharma Would appreciate if you could mark it as the answer, so this Q can be closed

Comment: PNG image should be supported in Python 3.8 and I suspect that `forward.png` is not a PNG actually.  If PNG is not supported in your tkinter version, then the exception should be on the line `back_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/back.png')` instead.

Comment: Do you know for a fact this data is in png format, or could it be in some other format but with ".png" as the suffix of the file?

Comment: @ShivenSharma ive added an answer, do mark it as the answer, if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CASE 1:**

Issue might be because png is not supported by your version of tkinter. So here is how to proceed using `PIL`/`Pillow`.

Start by installing it, say this in your terminal.

```
pip install Pillow
```

then...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk #import it
....
back_btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/back.png')) #instantiate the image
```

You can replicate the same format for the rest of the image files too.

One advantage is, with this, you can also resize you images.

**CASE 2:**

The error might also be because the file is not in the right format, are you sure you converted it correctly or is the file corrupted? You might want to check all these, and do the proper method for conversion(if converted by changing extension only). Keep in mind, if a file `hello.jpg` is to be converted to png, you should use a software or an online website to do so, but not renaming the file to `hello.png`.

Hope this helped, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: If PNG is not supported by the `tkinter` used, the exception should be on the line `back_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='images/back.png')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use PIL :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

root.title("Creeper Awww Man MP3 Player")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Create Playlist Box 
playlist_box = Listbox(
    root,
    bg = "black",
    fg = "#4666FF",
    width = 60
)
playlist_box.pack(pady=20)

back_btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('back.png').resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)) 
# .resize(xx, xx) ,, changing image size


# Create Button Frame
control_frame = Frame(root)
control_frame.pack(pady=20)

# Create Play/Stop etc Buttons
back_button = Button(control_frame, image=back_btn_img,)


back_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)



root.mainloop()
```